# How to search by a date with ContentSearch and IObjectIndexers

Tags: solr, content-search

I have a generic search method which should be able to search based on any field.
I have something like this:

> criteria = x => x[FieldName] == fieldValue;

This works well for strings but, how can I use it for a value of type DateTime greater than?
We have tried something like this but doesn't work.

> criteria = x => DateTime.Parse(x[FieldName]) >= EndDate);

Any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not strongly typing the fields to be searched against?

Comment: Simply because this is a repository that should be able to search anything. To have strong types, I need to know the type, isn't it? This is a migration from a Lucene implementation, and I can't redo the whole application. It was generic before, it is generic now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i found the answer myself. I'm not really sure why it works, but apparently it does work:

> criteria = x => ((DateTime)x[(ObjectIndexerKey)FieldName]) >=
>   StartDate;

I think the difference with the original code is:
The original code is parsing the value of the field as DateTime, and then doing the comparison, while the solution, marks the field as a DataTime object, to later do the comparison. Similar, but not the same.

I'm happy to accept somebody else's answer if it includes a better explanation ;-)